# How to retrieve the querystring in Sharepoint itemadded event

Tags: c#, sharepoint, events

Please help.

I have two different lists from within one site.

In one list, I have appended a querystring to the new form which will represent the EMP_ID of the user. In here, I have a hidden field "Name" to represent the record filled out by the user. This "Name" field is referenced from the other table with the EMP_ID value.

The following is my code:

```
        try
        {
            SPSite ohportal = new SPSite("http://moss2007dev:1234");
            SPWeb site = ohportal.OpenWeb();
            SPList vitality = site.Lists[properties.ListId];
            SPList employees = site.Lists["Employees List"];
            SPListItemCollection vitalityCollection = vitality.Items;
            SPListItemCollection employeesCollection = employees.Items;

            SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

            string empId = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["EMP_ID"].ToString();
            foreach(SPListItem item in employeesCollection)
            {
                if(item["EMP_ID"].Equals(empId)){
                    string name = item["Name"].ToString();
                    currentItem["Name"] = name;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = "ERROR: " + err.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't think you'll be able to access a page's querystring parameters from within an event receiver. As a workaround, I would suggest populating an EMP_ID field in your SPListItem using JavaScript.

<strike>Second, wouldn't the "Created By" system field hold the user who created the record?</strike>

For example, putting this JavaScript on your EditForm.aspx to populate a field named 'Emp ID Field' from the EMP_ID parameter:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/SPUtility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function SetValueFromURL(fieldName,queryParamName) {
    var queryParams = location.href.toQueryParams();
    if (queryParams != null && queryParams[queryParamName] != null) {
        SPUtility.GetSPField(fieldName).SetValue(decodeURI(queryParams[queryParamName]));
    }
}

Event.observe(window,'load',function(){
    try {

        // TODO: Put your code here
        SetValueFromURL('Emp ID Field', 'EMP_ID');

    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.toString());
    }
});

</script>
```

This is using [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/) (full disclosure, this library is maintained by me).

Then, in your event receiver, you can access the EMP ID to lookup the correct name.

```
try
{
    // same code...

    SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

    // **CHANGED** get the current employee's ID from the current SPListItem
    string empId = currentItem["Emp ID Field"].ToString();
    foreach(SPListItem item in employeesCollection)
    {
        if(item["EMP_ID"].Equals(empId)){
            string name = item["Name"].ToString();
            currentItem["Name"] = name;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    properties.ErrorMessage = "ERROR: " + err.Message;
}
```

Some other things I noticed with your code...

1. I think you might have problems trying to update `properties.ListItem`. I think you might need to update `AfterProperties` instead ([take a look at this very handy reference](http://www.synergyonline.com/blog/blog-moss/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=fcb287b5-7a1a-4206-a04f-2a97805e4a25&ID=25)).
2. You can make your lookup more efficient by not iterating over every item in the list. Use either an [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx) object or [SPList.GetItemById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyid%28office.12%29.aspx) if EMP_ID is the auto-generated SharePoint ID.

For example:

```
try
{
    SPSite ohportal = new SPSite("http://moss2007dev:1234");
    SPWeb site = ohportal.OpenWeb();
    SPList vitality = site.Lists[properties.ListId];
    SPList employees = site.Lists["Employees List"];
    SPListItemCollection vitalityCollection = vitality.Items;
    SPListItemCollection employeesCollection = employees.Items;

    SPListItem currentItem = properties.ListItem;

    // lookup the employees name
    string empId = currentItem["EMP_ID"].ToString();
    SPListItem employee = list.GetItemById(Int32.Parse(empId));
    properties.AfterProperties["Name"] = employee["Name"].ToString();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    properties.ErrorMessage = "ERROR: " + err.Message;
}
```

Comment: Hi Kit, The "Created By" column is useless in this case because there would only be one user who creates the item, i.e. the doctor. So, what I need is to have an identifier to whom that specific item belongs, where filtering could be done. I would look into the above option. Thanks for the quick response. :)

Comment: Hi Kit, in the above code, how can I refer to another list in the same site that would determine my condition for the EMP_ID??

Comment: Jane, I think I probably didn't include enough detail in my answer (which has been updated, please take a look). Essentially, you'd use the JavaScript to populate a field so that you could reference it in your event receiver (since you can't access the QueryString).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, but you should try the ItemAdding event, which sync

Comment: I have also called the HttpContext within the ItemAdding event and still returns null.

Comment: makes sense as the event receiver does not run in the context of the http request